# .htaccess file causing 500 internal server error

Tags: .htaccess

My .htaccess file produces a 500 internal server error.
File:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Fret Rolland"
AuthUserFile /home/orbitppc/public_html/merch/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

SetEnv RUNTIME_ENVIRONMENT "production"
```

After some debugging I have concluded that the error is here `SetEnv RUNTIME_ENVIRONMENT "production"` I do not understand what I did wrong here and why is this causing an error. Any advice about what the issue might be? Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Check your Apache error.log for exact cause of 500 error

Comment: make sure you have **mod_env** enabled also